# Globally set Jackson JsonIgnoreProperties in an excecutable jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a basic spring boot server built by maven to store all JSON objects which will be used as an executable jar by other services. It does not have a main or Springbootapplication.

I need to globally set the JsonIgnoreProperties in this project. Is it possible?

I tried putting the following in application.properties

spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false

and I dont know how to use it.

Comment: I think you can load via Spring's dependency injection.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?